# Foreign key constraint failure

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a new script which has a foreign key error.

I have the following tables: `request`, `category` and `request_category`.

There are now 6 categories in table `category`, so that's all good.
My script inserts the data into the `request` table and after that it tries to add an entry to `request_category` but this is where it fails.

The code:

```
$oUser = new User();
$oUser->firstname = $this->oLibrary->Request->post('firstname');
$oUser->initials  = $this->oLibrary->Request->post('initials');
$oUser->lastname  = $this->oLibrary->Request->post('lastname');
$oUser->zip       = $this->oLibrary->Request->post('zip');
$oUser->city      = $this->oLibrary->Request->post('city');
$oUser->email     = $this->oLibrary->Request->post('email');
$oUser->setStatus(UserStatus::STATUS_PENDING);
$oUser->create();

$oRequest = new ServiceRequest();
$oRequest->title        = $this->oLibrary->Request->post('title');
$oRequest->description  = $this->oLibrary->Request->post('description');
$oRequest->user_id      = $oUser->id;
$oRequest->setStatus(RequestStatus::STATUS_INCOMPLETE);
$oRequest->create();

// above here goes fine

$oRequestCategory = new RequestCategory();
$oRequestCategory->category_id = $this->oLibrary->Request->post('category');
$oRequestCategory->request_id  = $oRequest->id;
$oRequestCategory->create();
```

I don't quite understand why it won't insert. I have checked and both keys the `request_table` requires are present in the database. When I try to do the insert in Workbench it throws the same error, So I guess it's a flaw in my database design somewhere. Could someone explain to me why I'm getting this foreign key error?

The error message itself:

```
ERROR 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ruiljedienst`.`request_category`, CONSTRAINT `fk_request_category_category1` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `category` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

SQL Statement:

INSERT INTO `ruiljedienst`.`request_category` (`category_id`, `request_id`) VALUES ('1', '1')
```

Here's a screenshot of the related database tables in MySQL workbench:

http://prntscr.com/2fwce6

Update:

```
show create table ruiljedienst.request_category
```

Results in :

```
CREATE TABLE `request_category` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `request_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`),
  KEY `fk_request_category_category1_idx` (`category_id`),
  KEY `fk_request_category_request1_idx` (`request_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_request_category_category1` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `category` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_request_category_request1` FOREIGN KEY (`request_id`) REFERENCES `request` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1'


select id from ruiljedienst.category
```

This gives:

http://prntscr.com/2fwhfl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a foreign key constraint on `category_id`, so you have to add `id=1` to the `category` table before you add the row to `request_category`.

Make sure that all the referenced tables use `ENGINE=InnoDB`.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response, but there are 6 entries in the category table with ID's 1 to 6 http://prntscr.com/2fwg5d

Comment: The error message says there isn't. Can you update your question with `show create table request_category` and `select id from category`?

Comment: try creating your first record in request_category in the workbench, sometimes you have to add the first value in the auto-increment column before the rest can be auto-generated

Comment: Gives me the same error :(

Comment: Well, you got me, I can't figure it out.

Comment: your foreign keys are tied to the indexes rather than the tables, what happens if you reference the tables instead?

Comment: Are all the tables using InnoDB?

Comment: @JeffHawthorne What do you mean by that? He has `REFERENCES category` in the FK constraint.

Comment: Barmar THANK YOU ! Darn, the category table was still on MyIsam :( Please add your answer !

Comment: I found that by googling _foreign key fails when id exists_. What did you search for before posting your question?